# view Changeset details by tfs sdk?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-sdk

i will click changeset Details

[image: view changeset deatils]

and can i use sdk to popup this window???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via command line as  follows: `tf changeset 13684`
I am not aware of a direct way to get the same kind of thing via SDK, but, if you have to do with code, you can always wrap the console-call.